# Firefox, Form is offset. Works in other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox

Hello in Firefox the form is offset. Have absolutly no idea why, because it works fine with chrome and internet-explorer. I'm using Firefox version 56.0 (32-Bit).

The form is designed with flexbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVmLP.jpg)

```
<form class="form wow fadeIn">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flexcontainer_new">
      <label for="name" >Dein Name: </label><br>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br>
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer_new margin_left_60" >
      <label for="email" >Deine Email: </label><br>
      <input class="input" type="text" name="email" id="email" ><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flexcontainer_new_2.0">
  <label class="margin-bottom_20" for="description" >Erzähl mir von deinem Projekt: </label><br>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<input href="" type="submit" value="Senden">
</form>

.flexcontainer_new{
  display:flex;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width:750px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexcontainer_new_2.0{
  display:flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: The given source is not enough to replicate the issue. (See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr5h2we3/), which looks completely different from your screenshot.) Are you using a framework/library you didn't mention here?

Comment: I'm using animate.css, jquery and wow.js

Comment: the problem is stackoverflow doesnt let me upload my whole code. I will upload the code and link it here.